# map.yaml resolution parameter

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I want to know what is the resolution parameter in map.yaml file. I read the documentation and it just says that "it is the resolution of the map, meters/pixels". I don't really understand what it means. What happens if I change the resolution? Does it increase or decrease the size or the map or it just increases the number of pixels? Also, what is the range of values that can be given here? There is no proper explanation in the documentation. Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376973/map.yaml-resolution-parameter/) by [Chan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56593/chan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-04-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is mapping in between real size and pixelated size.

Resolution parameter used to define your mapped area virtually.
suppose you has room of size 10m x 10m and you have mapped that room with your robot. so now you have occupancy grid of that room and want to use it in simulation.

Suppose your Occupancy grid image size is 1000 pixel by 1000 pixel.

now to adjust your pixelated occupancy grid to original size, your resolution should be 10/1000 = 0.01

In conclusion, **resolution = Real size(in meters) / pixelated size**

---

Originally posted by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) with karma: 328 on 2021-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56593/chan/) on 2021-04-26**:
Great explanation. How does the size of the occupancy grid gets determined?

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2021-04-26**:
go through [this](https://newscrewdriver.com/2018/09/21/ros-notes-map-resolution/). Hope you will find your answer here.